# Font Awesome Webpack Import not rendering Icons

Tags: npm, webpack, font-awesome

I've tried to follow the documentation on Font Awesome.  I have the pro version and have configured NPM for it.  I'm using webpack to compile but I'm having issues with it actually rendering.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is my app.js

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons'
import { far } from '@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons'
import { fal } from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons'
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'

library.add(fas, far, fal, fab);
```

I just dumped the following FA icons into my index file

```
<i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i> <!-- solid style of the question circle icon -->
<i class="far fa-question-circle"></i> <!-- regular style of the question circle icon -->
<i class="fal fa-question-circle"></i> <!-- light style of the question circle icon -->

<i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>        <!-- facebook brand icon-->
<i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>      <!-- facebook "f" brand icon-->
```

It doesn't seem to do anything with the icons and I don't have any errors compiling.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using this with React or VueJS?

Comment: It's laravel so I'm using laravel mix and will be using Vue

Comment: if you will be using vue then I recommend you use their vue font-awesome components - https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/vuejs

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Webpack expert by any means, but there's a little more configuration than just a simple import in order to get Font Awesome to work.

Now this may have changed with FA 5, but I would hope this method is still valid.

This post sums it up quite nicely and is pretty much identical to my current configuration:

[Webpack 2 and Font-Awesome Icon Importing](https://medium.com/@chanonroy/webpack-2-and-font-awesome-icon-importing-59df3364f35c)

The article has the following (in case the link goes dead):

You'll need a few prerequisite items:

```
npm install webpack file-loader css-loader sass-loader node-sass
```

--save-dev

And FA, which you probably already have:

```
npm install font-awesome --save
```

** Note: your paths may vary from mine **

In my Webpack module rules I setup to drop the FA assets into a fonts directory:

```
module: {
    rules: [{
            test: /\.(eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                limit: 10000,
                name: '[name].[ext]',
                outputPath: '/fonts/',    // where the fonts will go
                publicPath: '/assets'       // override the default path
            }
        }]
```

Once you have all the configurations set, you need to import FA into your main stylesheet:

```
$fa-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts";
@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';
```

You should then see the assets being pulled into when you run your Webpack build.

Comment: hey - this is an old post but I was wondering why you had a `limit` key in the options? `file-loader` has no mention of supporting a `limit` option: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#options -- I've also checked previous versions and theres no documentation around it

Comment: I can in all honesty say that I'm not sure. I *think* I was going back and forth between url-loader and file-loader to get things working and url-loader has a limit key if I'm not mistaken. I've since updated to Webpack 5 and you can just use Asset Modules which are built in.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that loading svg-core was the issue.  The expected behavior was for the  tags to be automatically replaced.  Since I was loading svg-core autoReplaceSvg was disabled.

> - Using the @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core package disables autoReplaceSvg and observeMutations by default.

[Font Awesome API -> Configuration](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/with-the-api/setup/configuration)